# Express.js: how to get assets gzipped

Tags: express, gzip

I use compress() middleware, put it the first in configure().

```
app.configure('all', function(){
  app.use(express.compress());
  ...
  app.use(express.static('public'), { maxAge: oneMonth });
})
```

How do I check that my content is gzipped? I've got a fricking strange situation:
1) On my dev machine: I reqeust localhost:4000/mystyle.css - DON'T see Content-encoding: gzip

2) When I deploy it on production if I request the file it self mydomain.com/mystyle.css - I SEE there see Content-encoding: gzip

3) I request mydomain.com and see in Network in chrome dev tools, find there mystyle.css and there I DON'T see Content-encoding: gzip

4) I use different services to check if my content is gzipped some says that it IS, some that it IS NOT.

WTF? Can some one explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is your use of app.configure. This is largely deprecated, but you're specifically using it such that you're looking for an `all` environment.

The [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure) explains: "This method remains for legacy reason, and is effectively an if statement as illustrated in the following snippets."

Instead, just use the app.use without wrapping them in a configure statement.

Comment: If you must, you can use `app.configure(function(){app.use()...})`

Comment: Actually yes, encoding now is present, thanks. By why this was an issue?

Comment: It was an issue because you hadn't set process.env.NODE_ENV to 'all'.

Comment: @dankohn but other configuration settings (like bodyParser, sessions) were applied.

Comment: That's curious. You could use a bunch of console.log statements to figure out exactly what was going on, but I wouldn't bother.