# How can I automatically minify express js assets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, minify

How can I minify frontend javascript/css of my express js app on the fly?
Is there a reason not to do it?

Comment: You would typically minify JS as part of a build process so you just do it once rather than on-demand on every single request.

Comment: As @mark-small has put it this is definitely a duplicate question. But for what it's worth what you are looking for is called gzipping (check Mark Small's answer) and can be achieved using [Express' Compression Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html)

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily want to minify your code on the fly, it will increase the amount of time it takes for the code to get to your user. Do it as @jfriend00 has put it, in your build process using snowpack/webpack/rollup/grunt or whatever bundler you want to use. Then let gzipping handle the compression for you.

Comment: @KitangaNday minification isnt gzipping. and minify + cache will avoid extra processing time.

Comment: This module should do it but im not sure its still supported. I cant make it minify my code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify (this one)

Comment: actually found out I  can also use postcss as middleware and have it cached by another module https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-middleware

Comment: @ramiwi yea I know this, gzipping is compression, I just didn't add it in my last post 'cause I figured we were all on the same page. Don't minify on server, minify during build process.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932563/express-js-how-to-get-assets-gzipped). Look at the answer(s) there, I think they will answer your question. Basically it states to use the `compress` middleware.

Comment: minification isnt gzipping. and minify + cache will avoid extra processing time. this should do it but im not sure its still supported. I cant make it minify my code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify (this one)

Comment: Minimizing is a good technique, but I've always gained more by zipping assets, but it really depends on the size of the file. Really you would want to combine both techniques, which the NPM page you reference also suggests. I would follow the example of doing both at https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify.